# Why do programs sometimes report out-of-memory errors when Windows is shutting down?

Tags: windows-7, memory, shutdown

This isn't a problem or anything, merely something I'm curious about - and I've only tested it on Windows 7.

When I shut down my computer (or something else sends a shut down request) and until the workstation actually shuts down, various programs often report out of memory errors. My browser (Opera), for instance, shows such an error when I open a new tab during that (brief) time. Programs running on .NET also throw `OutOfMemoryException`s when asked to do something 
"heavy" during that time.

I find it a little interesting. Why *this* error? Is it actually another error, merely being misreported? Does the OS stop responding to further memory requests when it's shutting down? Does it maybe even *shrink* the logical address range allocated to that process, before claiming it all back?

Comment: `OutOfMemoryException` mean you have an application with a memory leak and/or code that results in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Ramhound Not the case here. I'm referring to perfectly well-working programs, behaving this way specifically and exclusively in the brief time between the invocation of a Windows shutdown and the actual shutdown of the workstation.

Comment: never seen it before but a wild guess is maybe your pagefile / virtual memory is somehow shut down prior to applications. just a wild guess.  I know when i've had an out of memory issue.. it has been when my hard drive was running low, and the message windows gave was that virtual memory was low. So, if you get it on shutdown that makes me think maybe your virtual memory goes down prematurely for some reason.

Comment: @Ramhound well, if you were to rule out 'well behaving applications' as a cause, then I suppose that would that leave you with badly behaving applications -or- **an OS glitch**.

Comment: @Ramhound likewise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the system is in shutdown mode, it can refuse to grant additional memory allocation requests to programs.  Typically, programs will log/report this as out of memory, but really the reason is that the OS is shutting down and is cleaning up allocated resources NOT giving more out.

Like you observed, it's not a "real" problem, just a timing artifact... Opera trying to grab some additional memory at the same time the system is shutting down.  Presumably this happens because Opera hasn't either received or processed the system shutdown message before it has made its resource request.

Comment: that makes sense, but then as to addressing it- a question is- why is the timing off on his system.. or at least, how can he rectify it.

Comment: The timing isn't "off" on his system and there isn't a problem to fix or rectify.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the phrase "The timing is off", it's an expression You used the term "an artifact of funky timing". What you call "funky timing" means the same as "the timing is off".  And if he gets a message about out of memory, it's not ideal is it.. it'd be better if he didn't have "funky timing" and didn't get that message.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood funky to mean "bad" so I've edited my answer to remove it.  There's just nothing broken here, and so nothing to fix.

Comment: Actually, the right thing to fix here is for the authors of programs like Opera to correctly interpret the reason for the out of memory condition and log it correctly, assuming the OS supports it.

Comment: As I said in the question, it's not really a problem - just something I was curious about. In fact, I've never seen a Windows installation where the shutdown signal closes all applications immediately. I've always seen a few seconds of delay, in which I can fire up operations in running processes.

Comment: Does Opera do that on your machine too webmarc while windows shuts down?   ie. is that the standard behaviour for many apps?  I suppose I  am never opening programs while windows is shutting down, so hadn't noticed.. But do you get that on your machine  with many programs?  I suppose perhaps windows could prevent a program from starting up and shut any programs down prior to withdrawing virtual memory.

Comment: I've seen this on many otherwise healthy workstations in many different environments. It's clearly not a random event plaguing the OPs machine in particular.